# Spring security without password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

> We have a scenario where the admin user should be able to launch the
>   application by just entering the username of any user **without** entering the
>   password. This is required for testing purpose and in real production
>   environment we will use SSO pre authentication.

Can this be achieved with following stack?

- Spring - 3.2.17.RELEASE
- Spring Security - 3.2.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security store the references for current user in a `SecurityContext` object. Spring Security magic ensures (through thread local storage) that a thread correctly accesses its one.

You can allow a special action in your web app to dynamically change the `Authentication` in the `SecurityContext` through the static methods of the `SecurityContextHolder`.